# why golang sched runs differently when the variable is odd or even? Is it coincidence or doomed?

Tags: go, scheduler

I have a sample of golang code as follows(xx.go):

```
package main

import "runtime"

func main() {
    c2 := make(chan int)

     go func() {
        for v := range c2 {
            println("c2 =", v, "numof routines:", runtime.NumGoroutine())
        }
    }()

    for i:=1;i<=10001;i++{
        c2 <- i
        //runtime.Gosched()
    }
}
```

- When the loop count is odd,say 10001,the code will output all the numbers.
- when the loop count is even ,say 10000,the code will output all the numbers **but the last**!

Why is that?

I have tested numbers from as small as 2 to as large as 10000,they all obey the above rules!

the ENV is as follows:

`uname -a : Linux hadoopnode25232 2.6.18-308.16.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue Oct 2 22:01:43 EDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`go version : go version go1.1 linux/amd64`

I think it has something to do with the go sched.

I assemble the code:

`go tool 6g -S xx.go  > xx.s`

the only difference between 10000 and 10001 is :

```
33c33
< 0030 (xx.go:20) CMPQ    AX,$10001
---
> 0030 (xx.go:20) CMPQ    AX,$10000
```

And,last but not least, when I add `runtime.Gosched()`,everything runs well.

Answer (score 1):

When main returns, the program terminates. It will not wait for any goroutines to finish. So whether all goroutines finish in time or not depends on the scheduler, and by extension on a fair bit of randomness, coincidence and external factors. The difference between 1e4 and 1e4+1 iterations might be one of those factors that affects the scheduling in just that one bit that makes the goroutine finish in time.

If you really require the goroutine to finish before exitting, wait for it to finish, by employing for example a sync.WaitGroup.

Unrelated to the actual issue, your code is overly complex and unidiomatic for what it's doing. You could rewrite the goroutine function as follows:

```
for v := range c2 {
    println("c2 =", v,"numof routines:",runtime.NumGoroutine())
}
```

Comment: thanks,accepted your advice.It is just a sample of all the code.However,you do not explain why it is different between odd and even.

Comment: "God knows why.". It might even be different for two even or two odd numbers, or it might be different depending on the load of your CPU. There are *a lot* of factors playing into the scheduling, and you can't possibly look at all of them and go "Ah, for this number, it will work that way". Your program is wrong, and that's all that matters. It will never work reliably, and it's irrelevant if it works correctly sometimes, on someone's computer, with some number, during a full moon. It is, for all intents and purposes, random.

Comment: Going further, it might change with every change they make to the scheduler. It might change when using different implementations, it might change on different CPUs, and so on.

Comment: However,I do not think it is coincidence.I have tested many times on my machine.Maybe the go shced internals result in it.

Comment: It do has something to do with the CPU.Yes,When you add runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU()),it works well. And at the same time,I acknowledge that,the code writes badly without considering sync.

Answer (score 0):

You need sleep a second or block a while wait the goroutine is finish!!

Comment: thanks,this do works.But what I interested is the odd and even problem.